# Error 1064: combining multiple strings in Concat() function:MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am unable to execute the following procedure  and facing error:

> 1064 
>   Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB  server version for the right syntax to use near 'aid=ass333' at line 1

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ref_table`()
BEGIN

declare t_name varchar(20);
declare aid1 varchar(20);
declare get_email varchar(20);

set @aid1 := 'ass333';
set @t_name := (select table_name from aid_ref where aid=@aid1);

set @get_email= CONCAT("SELECT email FROM ",@t_Name,"where aid=",@aid1);

Prepare stmt FROM @get_email;

Execute stmt;

End
```

if i am executing the same procedure without (,"where aid=",@aid1);  in concat function then i get list of all emails in the function,however i need to get specific email id from this procedure

```
set @get_email= CONCAT("SELECT email FROM ",@t_Name,"where aid=",@aid1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably this line:

```
set @get_email = CONCAT("SELECT email FROM ", @t_Name, "where @aid=", @aid1);
```

One suspects that you are missing spaces:

```
set @get_email = CONCAT("SELECT email FROM ", @t_Name, " where @aid=", @aid1);
--------------------------------------------------------^
```

If the values are being provided from user input, then you should be using parameterized queries.

EDIT:

Presumably, your problem is a lack of single quotes around a value:

```
set @get_email = CONCAT("SELECT email FROM ", @t_Name, " where @aid = '", @aid1, "'");
```

Note that you should be using parameterized queries if you are passing parameter values into the query string.

Comment: I ran using  your code
 "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'ass333' in 'where clause'" .
I faced this error as well many times previously.